# Using Java generics in an interface to enforce implementation of a method with the implementing type as a parameter

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have an interface like this:

```
public interface DataObject {
    ...
    public void copyFrom(DataObject source);
    ...
}
```

And a class that implements it:

```
public class DataObjectImpl implements DataObject {
    ...
    @Override
    public void copyFrom(final DataObject source) {...}

    public void copyFrom(final DataObjectImpl source) {...}
    ...
}
```

Is there any way that I can enforce the implementation of a "public void copyFrom(DataObjectImpl source)" method in the DataObject interface, using generics or otherwise?

Comment: To be clear, I need the interface to specify both "public void copyFrom(DataObject source)" and "public void copyFrom(<Implementing Type> source)".

Comment: Why would you ever need that? (assuming LSP)

Comment: Your interface really shouldn't specify implementation details like this. As long as a class `implements DataObject`, it should be free to implement the methods however it wants to. Classes that use the `DataObject` will have no idea - and nor should they - how the methods are implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need to handle `copyFrom` differently if the `DataObject` it's given is the same type as the object itself, just do something like this:

```
public class DataObjectImpl implements DataObject {
  public void copyFrom(final DataObject source) {
    if (source instanceof DataObjectImpl) {
      ...
    }
    else {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

On the other hand, you *could* do it like this, using a different name for the method taking an implementation type. However, I don't see what good this does.

```
public interface DataObject<T extends DataObject<T>> {
  public void copyFrom(DataObject source);
  public void copyFromImpl(T source);
}

public class DataObjectImpl implements DataObject<DataObjectImpl> {
  public void copyFrom(final DataObject source) { ... }
  public void copyFromImpl(final DataObjectImpl source) { ... }
}
```

Comment: "public void copyFrom(T source);" has the same type erasure as "public void copyFrom(DataObject source);".  I need the interface to specify both.

Comment: @loeth: Why do you need that? If you need to handle things differently when the `copyFrom` parameter is a `DataObjectImpl` vs. when it's some other implementation of `DataObject`, just use the `copyFrom(DataObject source)` signature and do an `instanceof` check in the implementation.

Comment: I need to do this because currently, all classes implementing the interface do of course specify "public void copyFrom(DataObject source)", but our goal is to move towards the "public void copyFrom(DataObjectImpl source)" methods.  However, in the meantime we have hundreds of objects that we don't wish to remove the DataObject method from until the DataObjectImpl method has been specified in the interface for at least one version.

Answer (score 3):

You could reduce your code by simply doing:

```
interface DataObject {
   public <T> void copyFrom(T impl);
}
```

or to be more succinct:

```
interface DataObject {
   public <T extends DataObject> void copyFrom(T impl);
}
```

You could use this by calling:

```
o.copyFrom(new DataObjectImpl());
o.<DataObjectImpl> copyFrom(new DataObjectImpl());
```

Using generics, the implementation of DataObject is always going to be erased at runtime.  It seems counter intuitive to know about the implementation because you should be programming to the interface.  If I were you, I might look into [Data Transfer Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) or [cloning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_%28Java_method%29).

Like Josh Bloch says, `use interfaces only to define types`.

If your type was defined as:

```
interface DataObject {
   byte[] getData();
   Long getId();
   Timestamp getCreateDtTm();
}
```

Your impl might contain:

```
class DataObjectImpl implements DataObject {
   // member vars
   public DataObjectImpl(DataObject dataObject) {
      this.data = dataObject.getData();
      this.id = dataObject.getId();
      this.createDtTm = dataObject.getCreateDtTm();
   }
   //getters and setters
}
```

The implementation or copy strategy wouldn't matter because any implementation abides by the type contract and can be reduced to this clearly defined type.